# No bluetooth icon on top bar

Tags: bluetooth

I don't have any bluetooth icons on my top bar and the bluetooth apps won't respond to anything. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

Open up your terminal and enter this

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

When its finished the icon should be there

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! In addition to the icon, after installing blueman,  "Bluetooth Manager" can be used to manage your bluetooth devices.